# Using the same identifier for a Type and a Class: What is the semantic effect of that syntax?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to understand the details of Nested Properties, and this seems to be an excellent resource:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20332/Nested-Property-Binding

In the file `Order.cs` I found an unusual construct:

```
public Customer Customer
{
    get { return _customer; }
    set
    {
        _customer = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Customer");
    }
}
```

Notice how the identifier `Customer` is used with 2 different purposes. IIRC, neither C++ nor Java allows such confusing usage.

Does that incantation have a special meaning and consequences?

This time around, instead of asking for a quick tip, I am trying to learn the subject well ("If you give a man a fish, you feed him for a day. If you teach him how to fish, you feed him for a lifetime")

TIA

ps: I am not even sure whether my subject line is correct - Feel free to correct me.

Comment: It doesn't have any special meaning, it just means the developer couldn't think of two distinct names. In this particular case the compiler can figure out that the first Customer refers to the class and the second Customer is the name of the property because there is only one correct way to write that.

Comment: Right, java has no real properties, only that "convention based" stuff (which is horrible) and forces you to type useless boilerplate (`getXXX()` - `setXXX()`) - The C# compiler is smart enough to figure out which is a type and which is and identifier or property name in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None.

There is no special meaning, the compiler is smart enough to understand that a Type comes before a name, so in every case it can work it out.

Having said that, intellisense in Visual studio has less information to go on (as you type) and so can sometimes have more than one option. Consider when you have static members e.g.

```
public class Customer
{  
  public static Customer NewCustomer()
  ...

  public string Name { get;set;}
}
```

Now as you type the following

```
public class Order
{
   public Customer Customer { get;set; }
   public void DoSomething()
   {
       Customer.
```

What is the meaning of `Customer`? Is it a type? In which case we should give the user access to the `NewCustomer` method. Or is it the property? In this case they want the `Name` property.

What VS does is gives you access to both, because as soon as you pick one, then the meaning is clear.

Comment: What is "VM"? Virtual Model? Visual Model?

Comment: In WPF its the ViewModel part of MVVM, Model-View-ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

The first Customer refers to a Type called Customer.
The second one is the name of the property.

This has nothing unusual in C#.

In Java you would write:

```
Customer getCustomer()
void setCustomer(Customer customer)
```

C# provides a convinient way to declare both `getX()` and `setX()` in one single member, usually called `X`.